# javascript alert before php code

Tags: php, javascript

page:content display.php

```
<td width="100"><a onclick="return confirmSubmit()" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&table=labour_details&return=content_display.php"><img src="../images/delete.png" border="0" alt="delete"></a></td>
```

page:delete.php

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['table']))
    {
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $tablename=$_GET['table'];
        $return=$_GET['return'];




        if($tablename=="labour_details")
        {
                    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `labour_details` WHERE `id`='$id'");
                    $row_1=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
                    $labour_name= $row_1['labour_name'];

                    if($labour_name!="")
                    {
                        $str=mysql_query("DELETE FROM `labour_details` WHERE `id`='$id'");
                        if($str)
                        {
                            header("location:$return?msg=Record Deleted Successfully!&id=$id");
                        }else{
                            echo "Problem in deleting :";
                        }
                    }

        }

}
```

my problem is where to add alert so that before deleting record it show javascript massage if allow then it will delete record.

```
function confirmSubmit()
{
    var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to Delete this Entry?");
    if (agree)
        return true ;
    else
        return false ;
}
```

Comment: Just add a prompt in the confirmSubmit ?

Comment: I suggest you read about AJAX, mysqli and PDO.

Comment: In `confirmSubmit()` function ?

Comment: in confirmSubmit() if confirmSubmit() returns true then link href is followed if not it stays on the same page.

Comment: it should work as is: if the user doesn't confirm `confirmSubmit()`, the link is not followed and the `delete.php` link is not followed

Comment: i am new to javascript please help me out....

Comment: provide us your confirmSubmit() function.

Answer (score 3):

This line will show confirm dialogbox before redirect.

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are You sure?')">...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create the confirmSubmit() function

```
<script>
function confirmSubmit()
{
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Then you attach that to your A tag, as you have done..

```
<a href="..." onclick="return confirmSubmit();">blah</a>
```

Comment: and there is no need to conditional statement just return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?') in function body :P

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.confirm).

Then, the body of the `confirmSubmit` function would look something like:

```
function confirmSubmit() {
    return confirm ("Are you sure you want to do this?");    
}
```

This works due to how event handlers work in javascript. Confirm returns `true` when the user clicks OK and `false` when they click Cancel.

By returning a `true`/`false` value from an event handler function you tell the window whether to keep processing that event. Returning `false` (which happens when the user clicks Cancel) tells the browser to stop processing the event and not follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td width="100"><a onclick="confirmSubmit(id)"><img src="../images/delete.png" border="0" alt="delete"></a></td>




function confirmSubmit(delete_id)
{
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");

if(r==true)
{
         window.location.href = "delete.php?id="+delete_id"; ?>&table=labour_details&return=content_display.php"
    }
}
```

Comment: with my function you will surely get an alert box to confirm delete or not....... check it and try it out.....

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="delete.php">delete</a>
```